# App_DocumentBeforeClose vba word

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to create App_DocumentBeforeClose.

I used with this code:

In ThisDocument:

```
Private Sub Document_Open()
start
End Sub
```

In Modul

```
Sub start()
Dim X As New EventClassModule
Set X.App = Word.Application
End Sub
```

In class Mudel:

```
 Public WithEvents App As Word.Application

 Private Sub App_DocumentBeforeClose(ByVal Doc As Document, Cancel As
 Boolean)
 MsgBox "App_DocumentBeforeClose"
 End Sub
```

When i close document it's not show me the MsgBox, Why?

Thanks,

Tal

Comment: You have to instantiate the class: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821218.aspx#Initialize

Answer (score 0):

your sub runs correctly but `X` is instantiated  as a *procedure* scoped variable so that once `start()` ends, `X` goes out of scope and is not available to any subsequent `DocumentBeforeClose()` event triggering

you have to declare `X` as a `Public` variable

```
Public X As New EventClassModule  '<--| this way 'X' is "seen" throughout the entire life of the document


Sub start()
'    Dim X As New EventClassModule '<--| this way 'X' would be "seen" only at the moment 'start()' is running
    Set X.App = Word.Application
End Sub
```

Comment: @tal_sshh, did you get through it?